# Djikstra's Algorithm using Adjacency List and Priority queue in java

Tags: java, dijkstra

I am having trouble understand why my dijkstraShortestPath(int startVertex) function is not working properly. I am following pseudocode for my project, but I do not understand what I am doing wrong.

Only the walk for my start vertex is showing up for my algorithm.

I also have a DFS, but I am not sure if I should be using it in my dijkstraShortestPath method, and if I do, how do I implement it?

I think my issue is either in the "while loop" or the way I am initializing my priority queue named "pq".

Link to FULL code:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/b848b9ts5lrfn01/Graph%20copy.java?dl=0

Link to pseudocode: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tyia0sr3t9r8snf/Dijkstra%27s%20Algorithm%20%281%29.docx?dl=0

Link to requirements: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rq8km8rp4jvyxvp/Project%202%20Description-1%20%282%29.docx?dl=0

Below is the code for my Dijkstra Algorithm.

```
public void dijkstraShortestPaths(int startVertex) {
        // Initialize VARS and Arrays
        int count = 0, start = startVertex;
        int[] d;
        int[] parent;
        d = new int[nVertices];
        parent = new int[nVertices];
        DistNode u;

        // 10000 is MAX/Infinity
        for (int i = 0; i < nVertices; i++) {
            parent[i] = -1;
            d[i] = 10000;
        }

        // Initialize Start vertex distance to 0
        d[startVertex] = 0;

        // Setup Priotiry Queue
        PriorityQueue<DistNode> pq = new PriorityQueue<DistNode>();

        for(int i = 0; i < adjList[start].size(); i++){
            pq.add(new DistNode(adjList[start].get(i).destVertex, adjList[start].get(i).weight));

        }
        System.out.print(pq);

        //
        while (count < nVertices && !pq.isEmpty()) {
            // remove DistNode with d[u] value
            u = pq.remove();

            count++;
            System.out.println("\n\nu.vertex: " + u.vertex);
            // for each v in adjList[u] (adjacency list for vertex u)
            for(int i = 0; i < adjList[u.vertex].size();i++){
                // v
                int v = adjList[u.vertex].get(i).destVertex;
                System.out.println("v = " + v);
                // w(u,v)
                int vWt = adjList[u.vertex].get(i).weight;
                System.out.println("vWt = " + vWt + "\n");

                if((d[u.vertex] + vWt) < d[v]){
                    d[v] = d[u.vertex] + vWt;
                    parent[v] = u.vertex;
                    pq.add(new DistNode(v,d[v]));
                }   
            }            
        }
        printShortestPaths(start, d, parent);
    }
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: You are using Depth First Search for Dijkstra's algorithm? Shouldn't it be Breadth First Search?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your using a `PriorityQueue` is that the content of the the priority queue is unrelated to the content of the array `d`; and the statement:

```
pq.add(new DistNode(v,d[v]));
```

Should replace any `DistNode` in `pq` with vertex `v`, otherwise, you may visit the same vertex multiple times.

I'm not sure that the `PriorityQueue` is the right tool for the job.

Comment: Much appreciated!